# Ubuntu 20.04 Cannot Connect to Alcatel HH41NH Cellular Router

Tags: networking, internet, iwlwifi

I have a Acer Nitro 5 dual boot Ubuntu 20.04 and Windows 10.  The Windows 10 OS can easily connect to the Alcatel router; however, the Ubuntu side cannot. I am able to establish a hotspot from my iPhone and that Ubuntu can connect through and I've also tried other wireless connections with the same success. I cannot connect Ubuntu to the Alcatel router.  Below are the journal logs for the connection. Can anyone please assist?

```
Dec 13 11:47:00 V2 NetworkManager[924]: <info>  [1607849220.3423] device (wlp0s20f3): Activation: starting connection 'Alcatel' (e8f06811-abb6-481b-a713-a5aacb0cf81a)

Dec 13 11:47:00 V2 NetworkManager[924]: <info>  [1607849220.3434] device (wlp0s20f3): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')

Dec 13 11:47:00 V2 NetworkManager[924]: <info>  [1607849220.3438] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTING

Dec 13 11:47:00 V2 NetworkManager[924]: <info>  [1607849220.3441] device (wlp0s20f3): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')

Dec 13 11:47:00 V2 NetworkManager[924]: <info>  [1607849220.3444] device (wlp0s20f3): Activation: (wifi) access point 'Alcatel' has security, but secrets are required.

Dec 13 11:47:00 V2 NetworkManager[924]: <info>  [1607849220.3444] device (wlp0s20f3): state change: config -> need-auth (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')

Dec 13 11:47:00 V2 NetworkManager[924]: <info>  [1607849220.3446] sup-iface[0x55f15093b120,wlp0s20f3]: wps: type pbc start...

Dec 13 11:47:00 V2 NetworkManager[924]: <info>  [1607849220.3795] device (wlp0s20f3): state change: need-auth -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')

Dec 13 11:47:00 V2 NetworkManager[924]: <info>  [1607849220.3799] device (wlp0s20f3): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')

Dec 13 11:47:00 V2 NetworkManager[924]: <info>  [1607849220.3802] device (wlp0s20f3): Activation: (wifi) connection 'Alcatel' has security, and secrets exist.  No new secrets needed.

Dec 13 11:47:00 V2 NetworkManager[924]: <info>  [1607849220.3802] Config: added 'ssid' value 'Alcatel'

Dec 13 11:47:00 V2 NetworkManager[924]: <info>  [1607849220.3802] Config: added 'scan_ssid' value '1'

Dec 13 11:47:00 V2 NetworkManager[924]: <info>  [1607849220.3802] Config: added 'bgscan' value 'simple:30:-70:86400'

Dec 13 11:47:00 V2 NetworkManager[924]: <info>  [1607849220.3802] Config: added 'key_mgmt' value 'WPA-PSK WPA-PSK-SHA256 FT-PSK'

Dec 13 11:47:00 V2 NetworkManager[924]: <info>  [1607849220.3802] Config: added 'psk' value '<hidden>'

Dec 13 11:47:02 V2 NetworkManager[924]: <info>  [1607849222.3930] device (wlp0s20f3): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning

Dec 13 11:47:02 V2 NetworkManager[924]: <info>  [1607849222.3930] device (p2p-dev-wlp0s20f3): supplicant management interface state: disconnected -> scanning

Dec 13 11:47:05 V2 NetworkManager[924]: <info>  [1607849225.1042] device (wlp0s20f3): supplicant interface state: scanning -> authenticating

Dec 13 11:47:05 V2 NetworkManager[924]: <info>  [1607849225.1043] device (p2p-dev-wlp0s20f3): supplicant management interface state: scanning -> authenticating

Dec 13 11:47:05 V2 NetworkManager[924]: <info>  [1607849225.1330] device (wlp0s20f3): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> associating

Dec 13 11:47:05 V2 NetworkManager[924]: <info>  [1607849225.1331] device (p2p-dev-wlp0s20f3): supplicant management interface state: authenticating -> associating

Dec 13 11:47:05 V2 NetworkManager[924]: <info>  [1607849225.4905] device (wlp0s20f3): supplicant interface state: associating -> disconnected

Dec 13 11:47:05 V2 NetworkManager[924]: <info>  [1607849225.4906] device (p2p-dev-wlp0s20f3): supplicant management interface state: associating -> disconnected

Dec 13 11:47:05 V2 NetworkManager[924]: <info>  [1607849225.5902] device (wlp0s20f3): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning

Dec 13 11:47:05 V2 NetworkManager[924]: <info>  [1607849225.5907] device (p2p-dev-wlp0s20f3): supplicant management interface state: disconnected -> scanning

Dec 13 11:47:06 V2 NetworkManager[924]: <info>  [1607849226.6140] device (wlp0s20f3): supplicant interface state: scanning -> authenticating

Dec 13 11:47:06 V2 NetworkManager[924]: <info>  [1607849226.6141] device (p2p-dev-wlp0s20f3): supplicant management interface state: scanning -> authenticating

Dec 13 11:47:06 V2 NetworkManager[924]: <info>  [1607849226.7520] device (wlp0s20f3): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> associating

Dec 13 11:47:06 V2 NetworkManager[924]: <info>  [1607849226.7520] device (p2p-dev-wlp0s20f3): supplicant management interface state: authenticating -> associating

Dec 13 11:47:07 V2 NetworkManager[924]: <info>  [1607849227.1261] device (wlp0s20f3): supplicant interface state: associating -> disconnected

Dec 13 11:47:07 V2 NetworkManager[924]: <info>  [1607849227.1262] device (p2p-dev-wlp0s20f3): supplicant management interface state: associating -> disconnected

Dec 13 11:47:07 V2 NetworkManager[924]: <info>  [1607849227.6268] device (wlp0s20f3): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning

Dec 13 11:47:07 V2 NetworkManager[924]: <info>  [1607849227.6269] device (p2p-dev-wlp0s20f3): supplicant management interface state: disconnected -> scanning

Dec 13 11:47:08 V2 NetworkManager[924]: <info>  [1607849228.3028] device (wlp0s20f3): supplicant interface state: scanning -> authenticating

Dec 13 11:47:08 V2 NetworkManager[924]: <info>  [1607849228.3028] device (p2p-dev-wlp0s20f3): supplicant management interface state: scanning -> authenticating

Dec 13 11:47:08 V2 NetworkManager[924]: <info>  [1607849228.4286] device (wlp0s20f3): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> associating

Dec 13 11:47:08 V2 NetworkManager[924]: <info>  [1607849228.4286] device (p2p-dev-wlp0s20f3): supplicant management interface state: authenticating -> associating

Dec 13 11:47:08 V2 NetworkManager[924]: <info>  [1607849228.7912] device (wlp0s20f3): supplicant interface state: associating -> disconnected

Dec 13 11:47:08 V2 NetworkManager[924]: <info>  [1607849228.7913] device (p2p-dev-wlp0s20f3): supplicant management interface state: associating -> disconnected

Dec 13 11:47:09 V2 NetworkManager[924]: <info>  [1607849229.7915] device (wlp0s20f3): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning

Dec 13 11:47:09 V2 NetworkManager[924]: <info>  [1607849229.7915] device (p2p-dev-wlp0s20f3): supplicant management interface state: disconnected -> scanning

Dec 13 11:47:10 V2 NetworkManager[924]: <info>  [1607849230.4721] device (wlp0s20f3): supplicant interface state: scanning -> authenticating

Dec 13 11:47:10 V2 NetworkManager[924]: <info>  [1607849230.4721] device (p2p-dev-wlp0s20f3): supplicant management interface state: scanning -> authenticating

Dec 13 11:47:10 V2 NetworkManager[924]: <info>  [1607849230.6007] device (wlp0s20f3): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> associating

Dec 13 11:47:10 V2 NetworkManager[924]: <info>  [1607849230.6007] device (p2p-dev-wlp0s20f3): supplicant management interface state: authenticating -> associating

Dec 13 11:47:10 V2 NetworkManager[924]: <info>  [1607849230.9665] device (wlp0s20f3): supplicant interface state: associating -> disconnected

Dec 13 11:47:10 V2 NetworkManager[924]: <info>  [1607849230.9666] device (p2p-dev-wlp0s20f3): supplicant management interface state: associating -> disconnected

Dec 13 11:47:15 V2 NetworkManager[924]: <info>  [1607849235.9715] device (wlp0s20f3): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning

Dec 13 11:47:15 V2 NetworkManager[924]: <info>  [1607849235.9716] device (p2p-dev-wlp0s20f3): supplicant management interface state: disconnected -> scanning

Dec 13 11:47:20 V2 NetworkManager[924]: <info>  [1607849240.8306] device (wlp0s20f3): supplicant interface state: scanning -> authenticating

Dec 13 11:47:20 V2 NetworkManager[924]: <info>  [1607849240.8307] device (p2p-dev-wlp0s20f3): supplicant management interface state: scanning -> authenticating

Dec 13 11:47:20 V2 NetworkManager[924]: <info>  [1607849240.8612] device (wlp0s20f3): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> associating

Dec 13 11:47:20 V2 NetworkManager[924]: <info>  [1607849240.8613] device (p2p-dev-wlp0s20f3): supplicant management interface state: authenticating -> associating

Dec 13 11:47:21 V2 NetworkManager[924]: <info>  [1607849241.2044] device (wlp0s20f3): supplicant interface state: associating -> disconnected

Dec 13 11:47:21 V2 NetworkManager[924]: <info>  [1607849241.2045] device (p2p-dev-wlp0s20f3): supplicant management interface state: associating -> disconnected

Dec 13 11:47:25 V2 NetworkManager[924]: <warn>  [1607849245.7147] device (wlp0s20f3): Activation: (wifi) association took too long

Dec 13 11:47:25 V2 NetworkManager[924]: <info>  [1607849245.7148] device (wlp0s20f3): state change: config -> need-auth (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')

Dec 13 11:47:25 V2 NetworkManager[924]: <info>  [1607849245.7153] sup-iface[0x55f15093b120,wlp0s20f3]: wps: type pbc start...

Dec 13 11:47:25 V2 NetworkManager[924]: <warn>  [1607849245.7182] device (wlp0s20f3): Activation: (wifi) asking for new secrets

Dec 13 11:47:25 V2 NetworkManager[924]: <info>  [1607849245.7350] device (wlp0s20f3): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning

Dec 13 11:47:25 V2 NetworkManager[924]: <info>  [1607849245.7351] device (p2p-dev-wlp0s20f3): supplicant management interface state: disconnected -> scanning

Dec 13 11:47:37 V2 NetworkManager[924]: <info>  [1607849257.5885] device (wlp0s20f3): state change: need-auth -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')

Dec 13 11:47:37 V2 NetworkManager[924]: <info>  [1607849257.5896] device (wlp0s20f3): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')

Dec 13 11:47:37 V2 NetworkManager[924]: <info>  [1607849257.5907] device (wlp0s20f3): Activation: (wifi) connection 'Alcatel' has security, and secrets exist.  No new secrets needed.

Dec 13 11:47:37 V2 NetworkManager[924]: <info>  [1607849257.5908] Config: added 'ssid' value 'Alcatel'

Dec 13 11:47:37 V2 NetworkManager[924]: <info>  [1607849257.5909] Config: added 'scan_ssid' value '1'

Dec 13 11:47:37 V2 NetworkManager[924]: <info>  [1607849257.5909] Config: added 'bgscan' value 'simple:30:-70:86400'

Dec 13 11:47:37 V2 NetworkManager[924]: <info>  [1607849257.5909] Config: added 'key_mgmt' value 'WPA-PSK WPA-PSK-SHA256 FT-PSK'

Dec 13 11:47:37 V2 NetworkManager[924]: <info>  [1607849257.5909] Config: added 'psk' value '<hidden>'

Dec 13 11:47:37 V2 NetworkManager[924]: <info>  [1607849257.6209] device (wlp0s20f3): supplicant interface state: scanning -> authenticating

Dec 13 11:47:37 V2 NetworkManager[924]: <info>  [1607849257.6210] device (p2p-dev-wlp0s20f3): supplicant management interface state: scanning -> authenticating

Dec 13 11:47:37 V2 NetworkManager[924]: <info>  [1607849257.6507] device (wlp0s20f3): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> associating

Dec 13 11:47:37 V2 NetworkManager[924]: <info>  [1607849257.6507] device (p2p-dev-wlp0s20f3): supplicant management interface state: authenticating -> associating

Dec 13 11:47:38 V2 NetworkManager[924]: <info>  [1607849258.0147] device (wlp0s20f3): supplicant interface state: associating -> disconnected

Dec 13 11:47:38 V2 NetworkManager[924]: <info>  [1607849258.0148] device (p2p-dev-wlp0s20f3): supplicant management interface state: associating -> disconnected

Dec 13 11:47:48 V2 NetworkManager[924]: <info>  [1607849268.0229] device (wlp0s20f3): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning

Dec 13 11:47:48 V2 NetworkManager[924]: <info>  [1607849268.0230] device (p2p-dev-wlp0s20f3): supplicant management interface state: disconnected -> scanning

Dec 13 11:47:50 V2 NetworkManager[924]: <info>  [1607849270.3162] device (wlp0s20f3): supplicant interface state: scanning -> authenticating

Dec 13 11:47:50 V2 NetworkManager[924]: <info>  [1607849270.3162] device (p2p-dev-wlp0s20f3): supplicant management interface state: scanning -> authenticating

Dec 13 11:47:50 V2 NetworkManager[924]: <info>  [1607849270.3400] device (wlp0s20f3): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> associating

Dec 13 11:47:50 V2 NetworkManager[924]: <info>  [1607849270.3400] device (p2p-dev-wlp0s20f3): supplicant management interface state: authenticating -> associating

Dec 13 11:47:50 V2 NetworkManager[924]: <info>  [1607849270.6987] device (wlp0s20f3): supplicant interface state: associating -> disconnected

Dec 13 11:47:50 V2 NetworkManager[924]: <info>  [1607849270.6987] device (p2p-dev-wlp0s20f3): supplicant management interface state: associating -> disconnected

Dec 13 11:48:00 V2 NetworkManager[924]: <info>  [1607849280.6996] device (wlp0s20f3): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning

Dec 13 11:48:00 V2 NetworkManager[924]: <info>  [1607849280.6996] device (p2p-dev-wlp0s20f3): supplicant management interface state: disconnected -> scanning

Dec 13 11:48:02 V2 NetworkManager[924]: <warn>  [1607849282.7147] device (wlp0s20f3): Activation: (wifi) association took too long

Dec 13 11:48:02 V2 NetworkManager[924]: <info>  [1607849282.7148] device (wlp0s20f3): state change: config -> need-auth (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')

Dec 13 11:48:02 V2 NetworkManager[924]: <info>  [1607849282.7156] sup-iface[0x55f15093b120,wlp0s20f3]: wps: type pbc start...

Dec 13 11:48:02 V2 NetworkManager[924]: <warn>  [1607849282.7182] device (wlp0s20f3): Activation: (wifi) asking for new secrets

Dec 13 11:48:14 V2 NetworkManager[924]: <info>  [1607849294.0745] device (wlp0s20f3): state change: need-auth -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')

Dec 13 11:48:14 V2 NetworkManager[924]: <info>  [1607849294.0757] device (wlp0s20f3): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')

Dec 13 11:48:14 V2 NetworkManager[924]: <info>  [1607849294.0761] device (wlp0s20f3): Activation: (wifi) connection 'Alcatel' has security, and secrets exist.  No new secrets needed.

Dec 13 11:48:14 V2 NetworkManager[924]: <info>  [1607849294.0761] Config: added 'ssid' value 'Alcatel'

Dec 13 11:48:14 V2 NetworkManager[924]: <info>  [1607849294.0761] Config: added 'scan_ssid' value '1'

Dec 13 11:48:14 V2 NetworkManager[924]: <info>  [1607849294.0761] Config: added 'bgscan' value 'simple:30:-70:86400'

Dec 13 11:48:14 V2 NetworkManager[924]: <info>  [1607849294.0762] Config: added 'key_mgmt' value 'WPA-PSK WPA-PSK-SHA256 FT-PSK'

Dec 13 11:48:14 V2 NetworkManager[924]: <info>  [1607849294.0762] Config: added 'psk' value '<hidden>'

Dec 13 11:48:14 V2 NetworkManager[924]: <info>  [1607849294.0900] device (wlp0s20f3): supplicant interface state: scanning -> authenticating

Dec 13 11:48:14 V2 NetworkManager[924]: <info>  [1607849294.0901] device (p2p-dev-wlp0s20f3): supplicant management interface state: scanning -> authenticating

Dec 13 11:48:14 V2 NetworkManager[924]: <info>  [1607849294.1184] device (wlp0s20f3): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> associating

Dec 13 11:48:14 V2 NetworkManager[924]: <info>  [1607849294.1185] device (p2p-dev-wlp0s20f3): supplicant management interface state: authenticating -> associating

Dec 13 11:48:14 V2 NetworkManager[924]: <info>  [1607849294.4925] device (wlp0s20f3): supplicant interface state: associating -> disconnected

Dec 13 11:48:14 V2 NetworkManager[924]: <info>  [1607849294.4926] device (p2p-dev-wlp0s20f3): supplicant management interface state: associating -> disconnected

Dec 13 11:48:24 V2 NetworkManager[924]: <info>  [1607849304.4969] device (wlp0s20f3): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning

Dec 13 11:48:24 V2 NetworkManager[924]: <info>  [1607849304.4970] device (p2p-dev-wlp0s20f3): supplicant management interface state: disconnected -> scanning

Dec 13 11:48:25 V2 NetworkManager[924]: <info>  [1607849305.3498] device (wlp0s20f3): supplicant interface state: scanning -> authenticating

Dec 13 11:48:25 V2 NetworkManager[924]: <info>  [1607849305.3499] device (p2p-dev-wlp0s20f3): supplicant management interface state: scanning -> authenticating

Dec 13 11:48:25 V2 NetworkManager[924]: <info>  [1607849305.3825] device (wlp0s20f3): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> associating

Dec 13 11:48:25 V2 NetworkManager[924]: <info>  [1607849305.3825] device (p2p-dev-wlp0s20f3): supplicant management interface state: authenticating -> associating

Dec 13 11:48:25 V2 NetworkManager[924]: <info>  [1607849305.7435] device (wlp0s20f3): supplicant interface state: associating -> disconnected

Dec 13 11:48:25 V2 NetworkManager[924]: <info>  [1607849305.7436] device (p2p-dev-wlp0s20f3): supplicant management interface state: associating -> disconnected

Dec 13 11:48:35 V2 NetworkManager[924]: <info>  [1607849315.7494] device (wlp0s20f3): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning

Dec 13 11:48:35 V2 NetworkManager[924]: <info>  [1607849315.7495] device (p2p-dev-wlp0s20f3): supplicant management interface state: disconnected -> scanning

Dec 13 11:48:39 V2 NetworkManager[924]: <warn>  [1607849319.7168] device (wlp0s20f3): Activation: (wifi) association took too long

Dec 13 11:48:39 V2 NetworkManager[924]: <info>  [1607849319.7169] device (wlp0s20f3): state change: config -> failed (reason 'no-secrets', sys-iface-state: 'managed')

Dec 13 11:48:39 V2 NetworkManager[924]: <info>  [1607849319.7180] manager: NetworkManager state is now DISCONNECTED

Dec 13 11:48:39 V2 NetworkManager[924]: <warn>  [1607849319.7213] device (wlp0s20f3): Activation: failed for connection 'Alcatel'

Dec 13 11:48:39 V2 NetworkManager[924]: <info>  [1607849319.7222] device (wlp0s20f3): state change: failed -> disconnected (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')

Dec 13 11:48:41 V2 NetworkManager[924]: <info>  [1607849321.9353] device (wlp0s20f3): supplicant interface state: scanning -> disconnected

Dec 13 11:48:41 V2 NetworkManager[924]: <info>  [1607849321.9353] device (p2p-dev-wlp0s20f3): supplicant management interface state: scanning -> disconnected
```